# Can "$\exists\mathcal{X}(R\cong C(\mathcal{X}))$" be expressed in "large" infinitary second-order logic?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, model-theory, higher-order-logics

*Originally [asked and bountied at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450489/which-rings-are-rings-of-continuous-functions) without success:*

Say that a ring $R$ is **spatial** iff there is some topological space $\mathcal{X}$ such that $R\cong C(\mathcal{X})$, where $C(\mathcal{X})$ is the ring of continuous functions from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is:

> Is spatiality definable in $\mathsf{SOL}_{\infty,\infty}$?

Here $\mathsf{SOL}_{\infty,\infty}$ is the "large" infinitary version of second-order logic (with the standard semantics!), in which arbitrary set-sized Boolean combinations and homogeneous blocks of quantifiers are allowed. This is an incredibly powerful logic - already in $\mathsf{FOL}_{\infty,\infty}$ (defined [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/#1)), each structure is characterized by a single sentence - but it still has limitations. The characterizations of spatiality I'm aware of (see [Eric Wofsey's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4460493/28111) to the above-linked question) seem to require more than $\mathsf{SOL}_{\infty,\infty}$, but that logic is strong enough that I have no idea how to begin attacking a *negative* answer.

*I've focused on $\mathsf{SOL}_{\infty,\infty}$ since - for me at least - it seems a plausible upper bound on what could count as an "algebraic" characterization of something.*

Comment: I don't quite see why the Gelfand duality style characterization cannot be formulated in second order logic. Could you clarify what part of the characterization doesn't work ? working with complex number for simplicity, I don't see why "there exists a norm making R a C* algebra" isn't working : Completeness for a fixed norm is definable in infinitary second order logic, the rest of the C* algebra axiom are just equation and "there exist a norm" can be phrased in terms of existence of a "unit ball" with certain property... What point am I messing ?

Comment: Oh. The point I am missing is that you want a characterization of rings of functions, and not of bounded functions. Sorry. got it.